# I have images that i have assigned to certain places, I know that the code is returning places however it is not plotting them on the map.

Tags: java, android, drawable, google-places-api

I have all the images in the drawable-hdpi. do i need to put them in the other drawable files? if its something to do with overlays could someone give me an example on how to treat each statement with the overlay?

```
package com.CS3040.Places;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import com.CS3040.Coursework.R;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class PlaceOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {
    private final GeoPoint point;
    private final Place place;
    private final Drawable marker;
    //private final Context context;

    public PlaceOverlayItem(Context context, Place p, String type) {
        super(p.getGeoPoint(), p.getName(), p.getFormatted_address());

        if(type.equals("restaurant"))
        { 
            //this.marker = 

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.restaurant);
            this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);

            //Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant);
            //d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            //this.marker = d;

//          Resources resources = context.getResources();
//          Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.restaurant);
//          this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bmp);

        }else if(type.equals("bar||club")){
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bars);
            this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);
        }else if(type.equals("amusement_park||aquarium||park||zoo")){
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.attractions);
            this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);
        }else if(type.equals("hotel||motel||bread_and_breakfast")){
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.hotels);
            this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);
        }else if(type.equals("shopping")){
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.shopping);
            this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);
        }else if(type.equals("food||meal_takeaway")){
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.fastfood);
            this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);
        }else{
            this.marker = null;
        }

        super.setMarker(this.marker);
        this.point = p.getGeoPoint();
        this.place = p;
    }

    /**
     * @return the point
     */
    public GeoPoint getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    /**
     * @return the place
     */
    public Place getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a problem with the way you are testing the type of the OverlayItem.

The condition `type.equals("bar||club")` will only be true if the type string is `"bar||club"`. Meaning that if type is "bar" it won't have any markers.

What I would suggest is to create a static Map:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> types = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

the initialise it on a static block:

```
static {
    types.put("bar", R.drawable.bars);
    types.put("club", R.drawable.bars);
    // ... the rest of mappings
}
```

and then on the constructor of the overlay simply do this:

```
public PlaceOverlayItem(Context context, Place p, String type) {
    super(p.getGeoPoint(), p.getName(), p.getFormatted_address());
    int resId = types.get(type);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resId);
    this.marker = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);
    super.setMarker(this.marker);
    this.point = p.getGeoPoint();
    this.place = p;
}
```

Alternatively you can also create a json file in the raw folder and parse it to obtain the mapping using: [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html). This way you can change the icons without having to go to the code and being able to reuse it in other classes.

Another alternative, if you feel brave to implement it, is to use annotations to create the map.

Good luck